# Co-occurrences of 「も」 and 「でも」 such as in 「何度も何度でもスキになる」

Tags: particles, particle-で, particle-も

Sentences below are all from Japanese songs:

「何度も何度でもスキになる」

「いつもいつでもみんなが側にいる」

「いつも何度でも夢を描こう」

Questions：

1. What effects does this 「XもXでも」 or 「XもYでも」 pattern bring about?
2. Is there any difference between the meaning/nuance of 「何度もスキになる/いつもみんなが側にいる」and that of 「何度でもスキになる/いつでもみんなが側にいる」?

Comment: The second one feels like "at any and all times".

Answer (score 2):

1) 「XもXでも」「XもYでも」is primarily used for emphasis. In English you might say, "I'll do it again and again!" Here, again is used twice to emphasize that you'll do it again. Similarly, in Japanese, 何度も何度でも, "Many many times, as many times (as it takes)", is repeated to emphasize the speaker's intention.

2) Primarily, emphasis will be lost. For example compare saying, "I'll fall in love with you many times!", compared to "I'll keeping falling in love with you, over and over and over, as much as it takes!"

Comment: The basic pattern of "again and again" is `Question-word も Question-word も`. `Q も Q でも` adds "any" nuance on the top of it.